# Dealing with method that may contain nulls

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a rather complicated while loop that loops through a list of possible event encounters in my dungeon crawling game.

One of the calculations that is performed during the loop, has to do with the time it takes to incant a spell.  That calculation is determined by this method.

```
    public static SpellTime GetSpellCastingTime(int dungeonLevel, IList<Combat> spells)
    {
        return spells[dungeonLevel].Spellbook.IncantTime.Value +
               spells[dungeonLevel].EncounterTime.Value.TimeOfDay;
    }
```

This works great 99% of the time.  However, sometimes either of these values could be null:

```
Spellbook.IncantTime.Value       //IncantTime is a nullable type
EncounterTime.Value.TimeOfDay    //EncounterTime is a nullable type
```

When they are null, all hell breaks lose and I get a

> System.InvalidOperationException : Nullable object must have a value

So I'm wondering how do I deal with this?  Should I have the method return a default "SpellTime" if either value is null?

Or maybe deal with it in the loop?

Something like:

```
if (GetSpellCastingTime(dungeonLevel, spells) != null) 
{ ...process... }
```

I'm leaning towards dealing with it in the loop.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with the `?.` operator? Are you familiar with the `??` operator? Are you familiar with how nullable arithmetic works? If not, then do some research on those; that will give you insight into how to structure your arithmetic.

Comment: Perhaps your method should be returning `SpellTime?` rather than `SpellTime`.

Comment: Do you need to calculate a `SpellTime` if either is `null`? Is there a natural way to represent "inapplicable"? And should they be assessed within the method or from the outside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you want to handle this is pretty nuanced as to whatever design direction you want to take. <s>You could wrap the entire thing in a try/catch, which will handle any errors that arise from the calculations and allow you to return a default value.</s>

A better alternative is to use the [safe-navigation operator](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/), `?.`. This operator is most commonly used with the [null coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator), `??`, in order to guarantee a value is returned.

In your situation, it would look something like `Spellbook?.IncantTime?.Value ?? 42;`. This will guarantee that you either return the non-null Spellbook's IncantTime.Value, *or* 42.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation along with the links really helped!

Comment: Any time. As a side note though this was a decently basic question with easy to find answers. I'm not trying to be rude but do your best to research! You will grow much quicker without relying on others, and it will help you become better at your Google-Fu ;)

Comment: Do not use try-catch to catch exceptions that could be avoided by simple checks.

Comment: @EricLippert following your sentiment try-catches would be unnecessary by our thousand if-checks. There's nothing wrong with using them for their intended purpose.

Comment: Indeed; the *intended* and *correct* usage for a `catch` is the *exogenous exception case* -- that is, the case where the exception is due to circumstances beyond control of the program, that cannot be checked with an `if`. The *necessary* usage for a `catch` is the *vexing exception* case, where poor program design prevents the developer from detecting a bad case with an `if`; try to avoid this pattern.  The *wrapped exception pattern* is also a good use for a `catch`. But exceptions that can be avoided with an `if` *should* be avoided with an `if`; that's by design.

Comment: So then -- honest question -- I've never run into a situation where a try-catch was outside of my control. That is, every T-C block was something I _could have_ prevented if I had known the error could occur and then account for it with an if-block or so. So if you imagine there are 20 scenarios in which a method could throw, and only one scenario in which everything is valid, do you write 20 checks, or have one catch-all that discards the entire function (as intended in these 20 bad scenarios)?

Comment: Of course you have run into such a situation; you've opened a file. What test with an `if` can you do that determines *before the file is open* whether opening will succeed?  Checking to see if the file exists doesn't work; the file could be deleted *after the check*.  Checking to see if the user has permission doesn't work; the permission could change *after the check*.  Checking to see if the network cable is unplugged doesn't work; the cable could become unplugged *after the check*.  You have to just `try` the operation and `catch` the exception because it can *always* fail.

Comment: Now, as for your scenario: your method has *preconditions*. Preconditions are things which *must be true when the method is called*. If a method has 20 preconditions then you *must* ensure that those 20 conditions are met; there are ways to do so that don't need an `if` in many cases. Suppose for example you have a `Max` method that gives you the maximum integer in an array. If you allocated the array yourself then *you don't need to check to see if the array is empty*, because you already ensured that when you allocated the array.

Comment: All valid points, thanks for the information on both fronts. It's not often you (or, well, I in this case) think about these sort of meta-scenarios that occur outside the realm of the logic of the program. I also have to admit that my programs are not so robust that every action is, in a sense, pre-screened for possible exceptions. I've updated my answer a bit to reflect the better usage of T/Catch

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, but one important aspect is what value to return if either are null, i.e. what is the default value?

You could utilize [HasValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094(v=vs.110).aspx)

For example: 
`return myNullObj.HasValue ? myNullObj.Value : someDefaultValue`

Comment: You would be better off using `GetValueOrDefault` which has the same semantics, or the `??` operator.

Comment: It is another viable option